# Sublime Text line wrap and commit messages

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, commit, commit-message, word-wrap

I use Sublime Text (3) for my default Git commit message editor. I try to follow Git conventions using a hard limit on the number of characters per line (50 for the first line and 72 for the rest). I currently have guides set up at those intervals for visual reference, however rather than manually having to put a line return at the end of 72 characters, I would love to have ST automatically insert a line return for me. Essentially, I want to be able to write without line returns, but have actual returns put in for wrapping instead of just visually wrapping in the editor. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a useful plugin for this (that I somehow missed in prior searches) called [AutoWrap](https://github.com/randy3k/AutoWrap). AutoWrap does exactly what I wanted and automatically wraps the line after a certain number of characters with a line return, and the settings for activating it and the number of characters can be set by syntax type. Here is my associated `Git Commit Message.sublime-settings` file (from `Packages/User`):

```
{
  "rulers": [50, 70],
  "spell_check": true,
  "auto_wrap": true,
  "auto_wrap_width": 70
}
```

The `auto_wrap` and `auto_wrap_width` lines work perfectly with the plugin and I can keep or remove the rulers as need be.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question :). Can you be more specific please to where should I put this configuration?

Comment: Find the packages directory in your machine (just Google it for your OS) and our this in a file inside the `User` subdirectory. The file can be titled anything, but I used the name in the answer.

Comment: I know where `User` folder is. Inside there I have Preferences.sublime-settings and some other files. Should I create a new txt file with `.sublime-settings` extension? I want this behaviour only for my commit messages. This is what I dont get. :D. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: `Git Commit Message` is its own syntax to Sublime, so it should be in a file called `Git Commit Message.sublime-settings`.

Comment: For future reference, the easiest thing to do is open a Git commit message in Sublime then choose **Preferences** > **Settings – Syntax Specific** (on a Mac the Preferences menu is under the **Sublime Text** menu). Then you can use these (or any other) settings and they'll only apply to files with that syntax. On my machine, for instance, the filename needed to be `commit-message.sublime-settings`.